# Access global variable in ruby unit tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, watir

I'm having problems using a global variable defined in the my test class, which then is referenced in the libraries file. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p392 and test-unit 2.5.4.

This is the code that runs the tests:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit_loader'
load '../lib/functions.rb'
require 'watir'

class Test_002 < Test::Unit::TestCase

  include Functions

  class << self
   def startup
      @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
      @browser.speed = :fast
    end

    def shutdown
      @browser.close
    end
  end

  def test_001_login
    login('some_url', 'some_user', 'some_passw')
  end
end
```

And this is part of the library that contains the login function:

```
require 'rubygems'

 module Functions 

  def login(url, user, passw)
    @browser.goto(url)
    ...
  end
end
```

This is the output:

```
Started
E
===============================================================================
Error: test_001_login(Test_002)
  NoMethodError: undefined method `goto' for nil:NilClass
(...)
     23:   end
     24:   
     25:   def test_001_login
  => 26:     login('some_url', 'some_user', 'some_passw')
     27:   end
     28:    
     29: end
===============================================================================

Finished in 3.0043 seconds.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

0.33 tests/s, 0.00 assertions/s
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance variables (ie @browser) defined in the `startup` method will not be available to the tests. Based on this old forum thread, http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/144884, it is by design:

> That behavior is by design. The "test isolation" ideal implies you shouldn't need to work too hard to get a clean slate each time a test case starts. Otherwise a test could rely on a @value from the previous test, and  could rely on it in a way you don't notice.
>
> Of course any other persistent variable could ruin test isolation. We don't stopand restart Ruby between each test case. But at least when it happens the @instance variables won't be to blame.

One workaround that I have used I have used to use the same browser across tests was to use a class variable (ie `@@browser`). The startup would look like the following. The other methods would similarly have to be updated to use `@@browser`.

```
def startup
  @@browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
  @@browser.speed = :fast
end
```

Comment: This makes sense. Maybe this is not the best setup for what I'm trying to achieve. I have created a test suite and the way I'm structuring it is to contain a test case automated in Watir and each of the blocks (step + validation) defined as a unit test case.

That's the reason why I'm trying to create the @browser instance and then run the rest of steps as unit tests. Is there maybe another better way to handle this?

Comment: It sounds like you are planning to have each test in the test case dependent on the prior test (ie test 002 is dependent on the browser state at the end of test 001). I worked with a test suite like that once; it was not ideal. If one test failed, you had to re-run everything to re-check the test. Sharing the browser instance (to save startup/shutdown of the browser) is fine. But the tests themselves should not be dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Your pre-test initialization code is not being run.

The TestUnit framework expects the setup code to be in a method named `setup` and the teardown code to be in a method named `teardown`

You have two options either rename the method `startup` to `setup` and the method `shutdown` to `teardown`, or, if you need setup/shutdown for some other purpose, create delegate methods:

```
def setup
  startup
end

def teardown
  shutdown
end
```

Comment: I believe the pre-test initialization code is being run. The newer version of test-unit has a [startup](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#method-c-startup) and [shutdown](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#method-c-shutdown) method.